# How to properly apply visited to links

Tags: php, css, html

I feel dumb for asking this question, but I can't seem to get my visited links to stay visited.

Below is the piece of the code that I'm trying to get the visited links to show as visited

```
<?php
 echo "<ul class=\"sm-lead-info\">";
    echo"<li><a href=\"index.php?displayby=serial&amp;displayvalue=$id\">" ."<h5>" . stripslashes($row['projectname']) ."</h5></a></li>";
    echo "<li>CGS Project Lead Assigned To: <span>$repman</span> in the $zone region.</li>";
    echo "<li>Posted on: $first</li>";
    echo "<li>Last updated on: $last</li>";
echo "</ul>";
echo"<div class=\"lead-divider\"></div>";
?>
```

CSS:

```
 .sm-lead-info li a:link{
        color: #034C9e;
    }
  .sm-lead-info li a:visited{
        color: red !important
  }
```

Here is a link to the site: http://consolidatedgypsum.ca/cgs-new-site/admin/project-leads/index.php

temporary username and password:

Username: Test1
password: test1234

If need be please let me know if you need to see the all the php code.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The PHP has zero to do with this. And I couldn't even login to your site with the credentials that you posted.

Comment: edited my password and below worked.

Comment: I have removed the username and password. Question has been answered. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at your site and you have a style on your h5 that overrides the a:visited link.  See my Chrome debug info below. Try this:

```
.sm-lead-info li a:visited h5{
        color: red !important
  }
```

[image: Debug CSS from your site]